# What's the difference between the particle は and the combined particles では and には?

Tags: grammar, particle-に, particle-は

I know that **は** can be translated as 'speaking of...' or 'as for...', but what's the difference between saying **ここは** 'speaking of here/as for here' to **ここには**?

In the same frame of reference from the previous question, what do combined particles (especially those combined with the particle は) mean?

Comment: Have you heard of the contrastive-は? You can search for it in this site.

Answer (score 2):

**The particles "*では*" and "*には*" contextualize the topic by providing a clarification.**

The only difference is the precision. I don't think this has an impact on the translation and meaning of the sentences to be honest. It is not mandatory to use them, unless we want to be clear.

"*では*" = allows you to contextualize a place where there is an action.

> ex: レストランでは食{た}べる。

"*には*" = allows you to contextualize a place where there is no action.

> ex: 公{こう}園{えん}には犬{いぬ}がいる。

The particles "*では*" and "*には*" should be seen as fusions of the particles "*で*" and "*は*", and "*に*" and "*は*".

Comment: Here you go : [how-should-i-format-my-questions-on-japanese-language-se](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/806/how-should-i-format-my-questions-on-japanese-language-se)

Comment: To put 振り仮名, simply put an English curly bracket after the text, then put the 振り仮名 in the brackets. Like such: 振{ふ}り仮名{がな}